# third party cookies and flash action script

Tags: flash, cookies

Let's say I have third party cookies enabled in my browser. I'm on a web site using a flash app that quietly submits network data via action script to another hostname. Can that other host track me using third party cookies? Are there any HTTP headers sent by Flash that can let the server know the difference between a request sent via action script and a regular HTTP browser request?

Pardon me if this is already answered somewhere else but I wasn't able to find an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer myself. Unless third party cookies are disabled in the browser, cookies are sent in the HTTP headers to the second host name depending of course on the crossdomain.xml policy.

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/cross_domain_policy.html